# Can't get the timing right as to when to call jquery using applescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, applescript

I am trying to simulate logging on as a specific user in microsoftoline.com using a combination of applescript and javascript (jquery).  First I need to know how many users are in the "previously logged into MSFT list". I try to do that by introspecting the number of rows listed in the MSFT signon screen. Once I have the "Numusers", then I iterate the HTML within each row to click on the userID div of interest. Problem is, I can't seem to get the timing right as to when to run the jquery to get that number of users. I have all the other parts working, just not the jquery part.

Here's my code thus far:

```
tell application "Safari"   
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:"http://login.microsoftonline.com"}
    delay 3
set NumUsers to do JavaScript "$('div.tile-container').length" in 
current tab of first window
display dialog NumUsers

end tell
```

In response, I get an error that states "The variable NumUsers is not defined."

I've tried doing numerous things including waiting for the page load before calling jquery.. but I can't seem to get that to work either.  That particular coding attempt looks like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
   if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    tell current tab of window 1 to set URL to "http://login.microsoftonline.com"

set the_state to missing value
repeat until the_state is "complete"
    set the_state to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1)
    log "busy"
    delay 0.2
end repeat
log "complete"
set NumUsers to do JavaScript "$('div.tile-container').length" in current tab of window 1
delay 2
display dialog NumUsers
end tell
```

I'm not married to using safari as the source browser.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't need to use jquery afterall.

This worked:

```
    set NumUsers to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('tile-container').length" in current tab of window 1
```